# mvc file upload and database insert

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, file-upload

I'm just getting my head wrapped around MVC in .net using VS 2013.

I need a little direction in regards to uploading a file (which is easy) but also inserting data about that image into a database. Specifically I want to allow the end user to enter a description, title etc. about the file being uploaded. On the back-end I want to also add to the meta data a 'Date Created', 'Path to the file', 'Category', and the File Name and a couple other pieces of data that will help with presenting files in the views. I don't want to insert the files in the DB but just use the path in the generated HTML to point to the physical file so the end user can view or download it.
Multiple file types are being used, Audio, Video, Documents, Images.

I can get the file upload to work but writing the controller to accept a file, and end user input, then also add the other fields I need into the database that the user never sees is where I'm stuck. Blending the file upload with the user fields and beack end data is confusing me on how to get all the pieces to work together.

So in short getting File Upload + User Input + non-User Input values all in the same View, Controller, and Model is what I need direction on.

Comment: What did you try and how is it not working?  We're happy to help you with your code, but can only offer limited help on descriptions of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to upload your image plus data in a multi-part form.

In your view you will create a POST form that uses "multipart/form-data" encoding, you can then include inputs for model data and your file upload control within the body of the form.  When it submits will will create a multi-part form, one part will contain the binary file and another part will contain your data.

On the controller action side you will receive the data with an action akin to

public ActionResult PostFile(MyModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file) {...}

There are numerous posts on SO with more details so I won't go into that.

Comment: This sounds like what I may need. I was just doing the file or the form request. Thanks